# Prometheus - Logging into running pods

Tags: prometheus

I am running prometheus in Kubernetes and trying to login to the running pod using the command below.

```
kubectl exec -it POD_NAME /bash
```

**Error**

> ERRO[0000] exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH" 
>       exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"

How to login to this running prometheus pod?

Comment: It could be silly but have you tried /bin/bash?

Comment: I tried /bin/bash, /bin/ksh. Still same error

Comment: What about /bin/sh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Container image doesn't contain /bin/bash, which is what Kube defaults to use to exec into the running container.

As a workaround you can try use kubectl and use /bin/sh.

Example: kubectl exec -it -- /bin/sh